# How can we use abstract, private, static, default interface methods in Java?

Tags: java, interface

While coding with Java lambdas I read about default methods in Java interfaces. So I tried to understand little more about the different types of methods in Java interfaces we can have. More importantly on the basis of their visibility and valid invoking.

Comment: Interesting generic read, with an important compromise.- Just in case it is helpful here. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 3):

Java interfaces currently support abstract, static, default, private Methods. Till JDK7 there were only abstract methods, but in Java8 static and default methods were introduced. Private methods were introduced with Java9. Some differences between these method types are as below:

- static, default, private methods have body but abstract methods don't
- abstract and default methods are termed as instance methods as they can be invoked by the implementing class, but the private static methods can only be invoked from static methods and static methods are invoked with interface name.
- Apart from abstract methods all the other method types must have a body.
- Interface methods are default public but can have private access as well. protected access is  not allowed. A static method can be private as well.

Let me put some code here in order to understand it in better way:

```
public interface MyInterface{

    void abstractMethod();

    private void privateMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hi, this is privateMethod");
    }

    private static void staticPrivateMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hi, this is staticPrivateMethod");
    }

    static void staticMethod() {
        //privateMethod();    // Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static contex
        System.out.println("Hi, this is staticMethod");
        staticPrivateMethod();
    }

    default void defaultMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hi, this is defaultMethod");
    }

    default void defaultMethod(int i) {
        System.out.println("Hi, this is defaultMethod with arg");
    }

}
```

```
public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterfaceImpl();

        MyInterface.staticMethod();
        // myInterface.staticMethod(); // Not allowed

        myInterface.defaultMethod();
        myInterface.defaultMethod(5);
        // MyInterface.defaultMethod(); // Not allowed
    }

    @Override
    public void abstractMethod() {}

    @Override
    public void defaultMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hi, this is MyInterfaceImpl defaultMethod");
    }
}
```